# CSS transitions in mobile - lags with FF, smooth with Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, performance, mobile

I want to understand how to solve this. When there's no much graphics on the screen(images, background images etc), the transition works normally(or just close enough to consider as OK), but when there's graphics(static) on the page, the transition became unseeable. It's very, very laggy with mobile version of FireFox, and default android browser, but Chrome(mobile) on android is doing just fine. Didn't test it with apple, would be nice to hear how is it doing there too, but the main question is how to solve this, so it will work as intended on FF and default android browser as well.

**Update:** It would be great to see how to force GPU acceleration with this example, because I was failed forcing it, or at least, it didn't improve performance even slightly. I used the following code for background image(moved it for container for not applying to entire body), input and div

**Code:**

```
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
-webkit-perspective: 1000;
-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
transform: translateZ(0);
```

**HTML:**

```
<span>
  <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/teams/new/1-freepik.jpg" alt="">
  <img src="https://material.io/guidelines/static/images/callouts/default.svg" alt="">
  <img src="https://maxcdn.icons8.com/Share/icon/Cinema//martian_filled1600.png" alt="">
</span>
<div>
  <input type="text" class="test">
</div>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
```

**CSS:**

```
body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: url("http://static.boredpanda.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/how-photographers-photoshop-their-images-landscape-photography-peter-stewart-22b.jpg") no-repeat 100% 50%;
    background-size: cover;
}
span {
  display:block;
  margin: 200px auto;
  background: #fff;
  width: 300px;
  text-align:center;
}
div {
  background: #333;
  margin: 10px auto;
  text-align: center;
  width: 300px;
}
img {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.test {
  margin: 20px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
.test:focus {
  margin-top: 100px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
```

Comment: I think you should specify what transition should apply to: **css property**

Comment: @fadifannoun Could you please elaborate what you mean? There's only one thing here with css transition - `.test`.

Comment: I believe fadifannoun is saying to specify the attribute you are going to transition, for example:
<code>
.test {
  margin: 20px;
  transition: margin-top 0.5s;
}
</code>

Also there is no use in specifying the transition on the :focus as it needs to live on the base .test class.

I have cleaned up your code a little here and seems to be performing fine on firefox mobile without the forced GPU acceleration you were attempting: [http://codepen.io/jaylandro/full/rybPag/](http://codepen.io/jaylandro/full/rybPag/)

Comment: @jayla Thanks, could you please tell me how did you perform the testing? What device?

Comment: Droid turbo 2 Android 7

Comment: I've tested it with Android 5. Thanks for informing me about that. It's helpful